# How to call search via csom without using Sharepoint authentication (username password)

Tags: sharepoint, csom

I'm using csom to call search without using username and password on the site. However when I found on the internet, nothing solve my problem.

Therefore, I want to ask that if there is any package to solve it and the way to solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Search API for anonymous users, we can configure Search REST API for anonymous users in server side.

You can refer to the article here: [Configuring SharePoint 2013 Search REST API for anonymous users](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/configuring-sharepoint-2013-search-rest-api-anonymous-users/)

Comment: OK, let me tried that. Can we use csom for anonymous users instead of configure REST API?